# Display Leaflet map per country

Tags: html, cordova, dictionary, geolocation, javascript

I'm developing a mobile application on phonegap.
For the Geolocation I'm using Leaflet "a JavaScript library for mobile-friendly maps"
and I just want to know if it is possible to display the map per country without having access to the others. So the user can just navigate in his country.

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet allows you to set limits on zooming and panning.
One solution would be to just limit the viewable area of the map to the coordinates needed for certain countries.

I am quite sure that there is geodata available out there giving you the highest/lowest latitude and longitude values per country (sort of a bounding box around a countries borders), so you could just limit the viewable area to those values.

To limit the viewable area use

```
Map.maxBounds(..LatLngBounds..)
```

More here http://leafletjs.com/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [this bug in the GitHub issue tracker for Leaflet](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/313), it seems that this is not possible at the moment.

Comment: ok,but instead of displaying the map per country is there any way to limit the navigation Area for the User?

Comment: The linked bug is a general problem, it seems that it is not possible to limit the navigation area in any way at the moment.